# Show Component Based on Routing on Default Address in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular9

I'm trying to show one of these components as the default one when my app is loaded:

```
<!--I want to show this one-->
<app-ms-power-automate *ngIf="router == '/ms-power-automate'"></app-ms-power-automate>
<app-uipath *ngIf="router == '/uipath'"></app-uipath>
```

I tried this:

```
<app-ms-power-automate *ngIf="router == '/ms-power-automate' || router == '/'"></app-ms-power-automate>
```

Or this:

```
<app-ms-power-automate *ngIf="router == '/ms-power-automate' || router == ''"></app-ms-power-automate>
```

And they keep showing me an empty view. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without knowing anything, I'd say that your `*ngIf`'s are all resolving to `false`.

Comment: You can use `===` in typescript, also, it is useful to console.log your router variable to see what it contians

Comment: Hi @mikegross, in all cases it prints /

Comment: Then you ave to work on this part. Use ActivedRoute https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute

Comment: While using ActivatedRoute might work, best practice in Angular would be to add a routing module:https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Why are not adding the required component on the app.component.html?

Comment: Hi @Harish, both are there, but I need to show them in different moments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my question, I defined a default Path in the `app-routing.module.ts` like this:

```
{ path: '**', component: MsPowerAutomateComponent }
```

It's using a **Wildcard**, more info:

https://angular.io/guide/router

Also, I needed to add the hash strategy:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
```

To avoid error 404 errors. Info from here:

https://medium.com/wineofbits/angular-2-routing-404-page-not-found-on-refresh-a9a0f5786268